How would I round a number to a grid using python?
I would like to know how to round numbers to a grid using python.
Here is pseudo-code to demonstrate:
GRID_SIZE = 20

def snap_function():
    # snap here
    pass

snapped_number = snap_function(68)
print(snapped_number)
# result is 60

I don't know if I gave enough, thanks!

Also for higher numbers too like 156 and up to 2000

use // or modulo ? (68 // 20) * 20 ? 68 - (68 % 20) ?

The modulo is the way to go. But you might want to offset by half the grid size if you want to take the center instead of the top left corner as the reference point for each cell. If you don't offer, then the cell 0 will not only contain the range 0..1 but also -1..0 making this cell twice as big as the others.

def snap_function(x,grid_size):
     # x//y will give you the modulo 
     return (x//grid_size) * grid_size

print(snap_function(68,20))

output: 60
